# Makefile variable substitution apparently not done even though := is used in declaration

Tags: linux, variables, makefile, kbuild

I have a main kernel module with which other kernel modules communicate. I have structured the modules like this (conceptually):

```
main module/
           |
            \drivers/
                    |
                    |\driver1
                    |\driver2
                     \driver3
```

Since these are kernel modules, I need to compile them like this:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules
```

However, since the Makefile of drivers can be called from previous directories, I need to do the `$(shell pwd)` before calling the other make (linux's make). So the Makefile now looks like this:

```
CURRENT_DIR := $(shell pwd)

.PHONY: all
all:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(CURRENT_DIR) modules
```

So far it is fine and it works perfectly. The problem is this: I have a file that the drivers need to include, so I have to give the include path to make. I first tried

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -I../..
```

and immediately understood why it doesn't work (relative path would be to /lib/module/... not to current directory). So I changed it to:

```
MAIN_MODULE_HOME := $(CURRENT_DIR)/../..
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -I$(MAIN_MODULE_HOME)
```

Oddly enough, this doesn't work! If I write

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Ipath/I/get/from/pwd/../..
```

manually, it compiles! Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? Before calling make, I `echo`ed `$(CURRENT_DIR)` and `$(MAIN_MODULE_HOME)` and the variables are meaningful.

I know that `EXTRA_CFLAGS` is not immediately evaluated, but since `CURRENT_DIR` and `MAIN_MODULE_HOME` are declared with `:=` I don't understand how things are getting messed up.

(If anyone can phrase the question title better, please do!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should pass EXTRA_CFLAGS to make like this:

```
$(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(CURRENT_DIR) \
           EXTRA_CFLAGS="$(EXTRA_CFLAGS)" modules
```

Update:

The content of driver1/Makefile is read twice: first - when you run `make` inside driver1 directory, second - by Kbuild system.

First, `CURRENT_DIR := $(shell pwd)` is evaluated to something like `/home/users/.../main module/drivers/driver1`. Second, Kbuild evaluates `CURRENT_DIR := $(shell pwd)` to something like `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-33-generic/`

That situation described in [LDD3, ch2, p24](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch02.pdf)

The trick is to write your makefile as follows:

```
# If KERNELRELEASE is defined, we've been invoked from the
# kernel build system and can use its language.
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
    obj-m := hello.o
# Otherwise we were called directly from the command
# line; invoke the kernel build system.
else
    KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
    PWD  := $(shell pwd)
default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
#endif
```

Comment: About the line you added: _Kbuild system doesn't use EXTRA_CFLAGS and some others variables from environment._ I doubt that would be true. I **did** use `EXTRA_CFLAGS` with -I/path/to/whatever and it was working. The problem was when /path/to/whatever got inside a variable. Otherwise, `EXTRA_CFLAGS` seemed to be used

Comment: You are right about that line, so I removed it and added new comment.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely because of recursive flavor of `EXTRA_CFLAGS`, which gets actually expanded in a sub-make, which doesn't have an access to `MAIN_MODULE_HOME` referred from it.

First, try to export `MAIN_MODULE_HOME`:

```
export MAIN_MODULE_HOME
```

I would also tried to *flatten* `EXTRA_CFLAGS` before using it (however, I'm not sure whether this is a good practice for Kbuild):

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS := $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)
```

Comment: I tried export, it didn't work (although what you said made perfect sense) and oddly enough, your second suggestion (flattening `EXTRA_CFLAGS` didn't work either.

Comment: @Shahbaz, well, just as a guess, may be Kbuild checks the origin of `EXTRA_CFLAGS` variable and if it comes not from command line it might be ignored.